# query functions or endpoint features in the sparql spec for describing the database / system itself

Tags: database, rdf, sparql, triplestore

In writing a thin client for querying SPARQL endpoints and monitoring the services, I found myself clumsily writing code (via queries and other strategies) to describe system information about the DB instance and other useful information. It led me to wonder if there is a better way.

Aside from the querying of data, are there any plans in the SPARQL spec or things that are already written in the spec for any of the following:

- describing the system itself
- describing the dataset itself
- describing any other diagnostic information

Comment: You might consider the vocabulary that gets used to configure Fuseki isntances;  see [Fuseki Configuration File](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/#fuseki-configuration-file).  That's obviously Fuseki specific, though you could probably reuse parts of it for any server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [SPARQL 1.1 Service Description](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-service-description/) W3 recommendation but unfortunately it is not well supported yet.

You can find more in Section 2 Endpoint Descriptions (page 3) of the fairly recent paper

> Buil-Aranda, Carlos, et al. ["SPARQL Web-Querying Infrastructure:
>   Ready for Action?."](http://vmwebsrv01.deri.ie/sites/default/files/publications/paperiswc.pdf) The Semantic Web–ISWC 2013. Springer Berlin
>   Heidelberg, 2013. 277-293.

It is in fact almost exactly about what you seem to be doing so you might find more useful information there.

Otherwise, as @joshua-taylor says, there are some possibilities but most likely you will have to rely on triplestore-specific features. Unfortunately, not even the triple store is always identifiable via the Service Description `Server` field.